# How to get the Azure AD User Group Name from User Name (Identity Name) in C# MVC .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have the following code snippet to retrieve the AD user name with which I login to Application using Azure AD but Im unable to find the Group Name corresponding to the user name.

How can I get the group name from the user name?

```
var ClaimsPrincipal = HttpContext.User;
var ci =(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) ClaimsPrincipal.Identity;
var name= ci.Name.Split('@')[0];  //This gives the user name 
var groups = ci.FindAll(ClaimTypes.GroupSid);

var g2 = ci.Claims.Where(x => x.Type.Equals("groups")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't return Group Name.

I assume that you have set the `groupMembershipClaims` property to `SecurityGroup` in manifest.

Then you should be able to get the group id through your code.

After that, you need to [call Microsoft Graph API to list groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example).

You could get the detailed group information (including group name) based on the group id.

Comment: GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var group = await graphClient.Groups["GroupId"]
 .Request()
 .GetAsync();

Comment: But Im unable to add add nuget for Graph.Auth as its un available in Nuget which is needed for 
      var app= InteractiveAuthenticationProvider.CreateClientApplication("");
             //var authProvider = new  InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(app, new string[] { "User.Read" });

Comment: Any help here would be much appreciated.